# mysql: how to delete then insert all records of certain type?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's the situation:

- I have a main **admin** whose `id`, in the table `person` is `478`.
- this admin is supposed to handle partners, in the table `partners`.
- there's a table that "joins" them: `person_partners`.

Sometimes, some people add new partners, and I'd like to run a query that:

- either:

  - remove all links between *this* admin and partners, some kind of `DELETE * FROM person_partners where id_person=478`
  - re-insert all links between *this* admin and partners (= new partners will be inserted too), some kind of `INSERT INTO person_partners (id_person,id_partner) VALUES (478, SELECT id FROM partners)` (but this query give me this error: `ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row`)
- or simply insert all partners that are not yet in `person_partners` with `id_person=478`

Any idea?

Comment: You seem to have your own answers in the question - what bit were you asking about?

Comment: Quote of myself: `this query give me this error: ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row)` so it doesn't work and I'm trying to find out how to make it work. Sorry if I'm not clear enough... don't hesitate to edit my question to make it clearer! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like BugFinder said, "You seem to have your own answers in the question"

To fix the ERROR 1242 you have to write it like this:

```
INSERT INTO person_partners (id_person,id_partner) 
SELECT '478', id FROM partners;
```

Alternatively to "simply insert all partners that are not yet in person_partners with id_person=478" you can

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO person_partners (id_person,id_partner) 
SELECT '478', id FROM partners;
```

Read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO person_partners (id_person,id_partner) SELECT 478, ID FROM partners
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id_person=478;
```